# TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined google assistant

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-get, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm working on a Bus Stop google assistant script in node.js
I based it on the weather API example by Google. Given the right API key, the weather function will work and return the weather for a place on a date.

The Bus Stop API will return the correct output in the console.log, but the output does not get passed on to the `else if` statement where the function is called.

I get 2 errors:

1. `"Unhandled rejection"`  Which can be alleviated by commenting out the reject code in the callBusApi.
2. `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
   at callBusApi.then.catch (/user_code/index.js:45:9)
   at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)"` This is where it breaks. I think because it doesn't get the output from the function.

My script looks as follows:

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');

const host = 'api.worldweatheronline.com';
const wwoApiKey = 'enter a working key';

exports.weatherWebhook = (req, res, re) => {
  if(req.body.queryResult.intent['displayName'] == 'weather'){
    // Get the city and date from the request
    let city = req.body.queryResult.parameters['geo-city']; // city is a required param

    // Get the date for the weather forecast (if present)
    let date = '';
    if (req.body.queryResult.parameters['date']) {
      date = req.body.queryResult.parameters['date'];
      console.log('Date: ' + date);
    }

    // Call the weather API
    callWeatherApi(city, date).then((output) => {
      res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': output }); // Return the results of the weather API to Dialogflow
    }).catch(() => {
      res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': `I don't know the weather but I hope it's good!` });
    });
  }
 else if (req.body.queryResult.intent['displayName'] == 'mytestintent'){
  callBusApi().then((output) => {
      re.json({ 'fulfillmentText': output }); // Return the results of the bus stop API to Dialogflow
    }).catch(() => {
      re.json({ 'fulfillmentText': `I do not know when the bus goes.` });
     });
  }
};


function callBusApi () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get({host: 'v0.ovapi.nl', path: '/stopareacode/beunav/departures/'}, (re) => {
    let boy = '';
    re.on('data', (d) => {boy+=d});
    re.on('end',() => {

      let response = JSON.parse(boy)
      var firstKey = Object.keys(response['beunav']['61120250']['Passes'])[0];
      var timeKey = Object.keys(response['beunav']['61120250']['Passes'][firstKey])[19];
      var destKey = Object.keys(response['beunav']['61120250']['Passes'][firstKey])[1];
      let destination = response['beunav']['61120250']['Passes'][firstKey][destKey];
      let datetime = response['beunav']['61120250']['Passes'][firstKey][timeKey];
      let fields = datetime.split('T');
      let time = fields[1];

      let output = `Next bus to ${destination} departs at ${time} .`;

      console.log(output)
      resolve(output);
      });
     re.on('error', (error) => {
       console.log(`Error talking to the busstop: ${error}`)
      reject();
       });
    });
  });
};


function callWeatherApi (city, date) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let path = '/premium/v1/weather.ashx?format=json&num_of_days=1' +
      '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(city) + '&key=' + wwoApiKey + '&date=' + date;
    console.log('API Request: ' + host + path);


    http.get({host: host, path: path}, (res) => {
      let body = '';
      res.on('data', (d) => { body += d; });
      res.on('end', () => {

        let response = JSON.parse(body);
        let forecast = response['data']['weather'][0];
        let location = response['data']['request'][0];
        let conditions = response['data']['current_condition'][0];
        let currentConditions = conditions['weatherDesc'][0]['value'];

        let output = `Current conditions in the ${location['type']} 
        ${location['query']} are ${currentConditions} with a projected high of
        ${forecast['maxtempC']}°C or ${forecast['maxtempF']}°F and a low of 
        ${forecast['mintempC']}°C or ${forecast['mintempF']}°F on 
        ${forecast['date']}.`;

        console.log(output);
        resolve(output);
      });
      res.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(`Error calling the weather API: ${error}`)
        reject();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: It seems that the `re` object is undefined. Where are you calling the `weatherWebhook()` function? Are the 3 parameters being passed to this function correctly?

Comment: Can you log the values of `re` and `output` inside `callBusApi().then()`?

Comment: No, since the `.then` is never executed because of the error. The `weatherWebhook()` function is called by DialogFlow. I understand that `re` must be undefined somehow, but why does the callWeatherApi work and the callBusApi not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your method has a parameter too much

```
exports.weatherWebhook = (req, res, re) => {
```

should be:

```
exports.weatherWebhook = (req, res) => {
```

And as well on the variable 're' used in the handling of the 'mytestintent' inside the webhook.

This explains the 'not defined' error when trying to set a json value on it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your 2 question: It usually comes when the value of the variable is not defined.

First check wheather you have defined the JSON variable in your .js file.
Or its in some other format.